# FOSUserBundle overriding register form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to override the register form from FOSUserBundle.

I have followed this page: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

I want that the form to contain these six inputs:

1. Salutation
2. first name
3. last name
4. e-mail
5. password
6. password confirm

My Folder Structure:

[enter link description here](http://davis-design.de/folder_struct.png)

My User Class:

```
    <?php

namespace Bundles\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit="3", message="The name is too short.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="255", message="The name is too long.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    //protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

My service.yml Data:

```
parameters:
services:
    frontendbundle.registration.form.type:
        class: Bundles\FrontendBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: frontend_user_registration  }
    frontendbundle.form.handler.registration:
        class: Bundles\FrontendBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler
        arguments: ["@fos_user.registration.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator"]
        scope: request
        public: false
```

My config.yml Data:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: main
user_class: Bundles\FrontendBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    form:
        type: frontend_user_registration
        handler: frontendbundle.form.handler.registration
```

My RegistrationFormType Class:

```
    <?php

namespace Bundles\FrontendBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('salutation')
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => "Bundles\FrontendBundle\Entity\User"
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'frontend_user_registration';
    }
}
```

How do I need to define the field here for my plan with the six inputs ?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does your bundle inherits from FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Hey Geoffrey, yes my Bundle inherits from FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

Just add field in your RegistrationFormType and the password field auto-generate a confirmation input.

```
<?php

namespace Bundles\FrontendBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('salutation')
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                )
             )
     ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => "Bundles\FrontendBundle\Entity\User"
));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'frontend_user_registration';
}
```

Comment: Hey Charly, thanks for your answer. I update this and in my Question i have to update too. Now i have Error two Message: **InvalidArgumentException: Unable to replace alias "frontendbundle.form.handler.registration" with "fos_user.registration.form.handler".**  and **InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "frontendbundle.form.handler.registration" does not exist.** You see at the top in my Question my actual config.yml and i don't know what is wrong?

Comment: You're welcome ! ;) For the first error you must change in config.yml the fos_user: registration: form: type: to : "frontend_user_registration" (I've edit it in your question).
For the second error (service doesn't exist) you must just change the name too in your services.yml ans in config.yml (change "FrontendBundle.form.handler.registration" in "frontendbundle.form.handler.registration")

Comment: Hey Charly thanks again for your answer. I update my config.yml and service.yml (in my Question too) but i have the same Error :(. I clear the cache but has not helped. Have i error in my two data?